# How to rotate a image in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, image-rotation

I have photos on my HD that on windows explorer it is shown correctly. But when I load those images from HD dynamically into *iReport*, it comes rotated 90CC.

How do I load it dynamically into report without this rotation? I can`t do it manually because the photos come from a software that save it on the HD automatically.

```
<image>
    <reportElement uuid="28888bfe-c320-48d3-a392-af1d844192fe" x="4" y="0" width="130" height="200"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{path} + $F{_THIS} + ".jpg"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the *GUI* designer *iReport*? The *JasperReports* engine does not rotate image on its own will. Can you post the sample of *jrxml* file and attach image to your post?

Comment: What version of jasper reports are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the jrxml and add the rotation attribute to the jr:barbecue element. (jasper reports 4.0.2 )

```
<jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="Code128" drawText="true" checksumRequired="true" rotation="Right">
```

Check this link if above approach is not working - [http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2936](http://dzone.com/snippets/java-rotate-90%C3%A2%C2%B090%C3%A2%C2%B0)